# Display problems in El Capitan on screen sharing

Tags: display, macos, mac-pro, screen-sharing

I have recently updated the OS in an old Mac Pro to El Capitan. Since then I have severe display problems. I must add that I access the system via screen sharing. The fonts are horribly blurred in menu bar drop-down menus, making them unreadable, and also in some packages the whole menu is diplaid in black. The first problem was sorted using the darkened menus and dock. But not the second problem.

[image: Drop down menu fonts unreadable]

[image: Menus went black]

Comment: When I say the problem was sorted when darkening top menu bar and dock, this is only true for the top bar menus. When I right click anywhere to get a menu the blurred fonts problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got the solution. Apart from enabling dark menu and dock all you have to do is to turn on "Increase contrast" option. See below:
[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: This helps but still does not completely solve the problem...